# Example of a Dedekind Domain which is not a PID

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, dedekind-domain

I am asked to show that $\mathbb R[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2-1)$ is a DD but not a PID.

Some quick observations I made are it is Noetherian, Normal (since $X^2-1$ is square free).

How do I show the following two claims?

1. All non zero prime ideals are maximal
2. Is is NOT a PID.

Comment: $\Bbb R[X] \subseteq \Bbb R[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2-1)$ is an integral extension of domains. Thus the two rings have the same dimension. To see that it is not a PID, show that $(X,Y)$ is not a principal ideal.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

1. For any field $F$, $F[X,Y]$  has Krull dimension $2$ and $X^2+Y^2-1$ generates a prime ideal in $\mathbf R[X,Y]$ since it is irreducible and the polynomial ring is  a U.F.D.